# CSS Grid Layout Module Level 1 - How long does it usually take from candidate recommendation to final spec?

Tags: css, w3c, css-grid

The W3C Candidate Recommendation was published 29 September 2016.

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/

Since Chrome/Firefox/IE implement the feature already (more or less complete and behind feature flags) the final spec by W3C will roughly be the release date for those browsers.

Based on the usual W3C process and the progress of this working group in particular - can someone estimate or roughly guess when the final spec will be out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rachel Andrew has recently blogged about this;

https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2016/09/29/css-grid-layout-module-level-1-at-candidate-recommendation/

She estimates early 2017 will see availability of this module in evergreen browsers without relying on an 'experimental' flag.

Rachel has [blogged extensively about CSS grid](https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/tag/cssgrid) and has also put together http://gridbyexample.com/